How to deal with random string in function name for cloudformation
I have built a cloudformation script that creates a dashboard. The problem I have is dealing with a lambda function name.
In the cloudformation script I have
[ "AWS/Lambda", "Invocations", "FunctionName, "SC-accountNumber-*-FunctionName" ]

I've replaced the account number and the function name and left the wildcard in. There is some other stuff too. This isn't working.
I've pasted the full name of the function in and the dashboard works fine. Something like
SC-0123456789-qw-sjdu5bd73hsn6-MyApiName

but my concern is that random string will change when we deploy a new version.
The type is metric if that makes a difference on how to deal with the randome string

Unfortunately wildcard is not inherently support wildcards (*) by Cloudwatch in the FunctionName dimension. You can only specify the exact function name.
the Lambda function is also seems to be created by a cloudformation stack also, so if it's possible it will be better to hardcode the lambda function name. or you can export it from the main stack, and import it back into the dashboard stack
Export
Outputs:
  LambdaFunctionName:
    Description: "The name of the Lambda function"
    Value: !Ref MyLambdaFunction
    Export:
      Name: MyLambdaFunctionName

Import
Parameters:
  LambdaFunctionName:
    Type: String
    Default: !ImportValue MyLambdaFunctionName

You can also, create an SSM parameter as part of the main stack and store the function name there, then whenever you deploy a new version, you need to re-deploy the dashboard script as well.
lastly you can create a Custom Resource can programmatically query the function name during CloudFormation stack (Dashbaord) creation or update.
